# How do I export and import Console2 settings?

Tags: console2

I have customized my [Console2](https://github.com/cbucher/console) on one windows PC and I want to have the same settings on 3 more windows PCs.

Where does Console2 save its settings? How do I export them into a file and import them on other PCs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config file is named `console.xml` and is usually located in `%appdata%/Roaming/Console/console.xml`. If not have a look in that folder where you have installed Console2 (possibly `%programfiles%/Console2/console.xml`).